# Executing a method in the Spring MVC from the JSP button

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with a Spring MVC app where I would like to execute a `POST` method after clicking a button in the JSP page. The landing page looks like,

[image]

I would like to execute the following Spring method after clicking the `Generate Address` button,

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/generateAddress")
    public String generateAddress() {    
        walletService.generateAddress();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

`What I would like to achieve`

after clicking the `Generate Address` button, I would like to make a POST request to the `generateAddress` method.

The JSP page with the button code,

```
<body class="page_container">
<div class="wallets_page">

    <form id="mnfrm" action="/" method="get" target="_blank">
        <div class="buttons_box">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">
                Generate address
            </button>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" <%= wallets.isEmpty() ? "disabled" : ""%>
                    onclick="setFormAction('mnfrm', '/balance')">Balance
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" <%= wallets.isEmpty() ? "disabled" : ""%>
                    onclick="setFormAction('mnfrm', '/transactions')">Transactions
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" <%= wallets.isEmpty() ? "disabled" : ""%>
                    onclick="setFormAction('mnfrm', '/sendMoney')">Send money
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="addresses_box">
            <label for="addressId">Address</label>
            <select id="addressId" name="id" class="form-control">
                <c:forEach var="wallet" items="${wallets}">
                    <option value="${wallet.id}"><c:out value="${wallet.address}"></c:out></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have tried to set an `onclick` in the `button` that doesn't work.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">
          Generate address
    </button>
```

Any suggestion of how to do it properly?

`More Info`

This is the method opens the landing page of `main.jsp`,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String showBitcoinWallet(final Model model) {
        List<WalletInfo> wallets = walletService.getAllWallets();
        model.addAttribute("wallets", wallets);
        return "main";
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve. If you want to make an ajax call(without reloading the page) then your second post is the right way. On the other hand if you want to make a normal post call(form submission which will reload the page) then you need to correct your controller code. Please refer this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: I make the question simpler and  clarified about what I would like to achieve

Comment: Then you should follow the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I have achieved it with `Ajax POST` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with the button id and an `Ajax` POST request combined. The solution is very simple and I needed an `mvn clean` before it would work out.

Address button

```
<button id="genAddress" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">
                Generate address
            </button>
```

The `Ajax POST` request,

```
<script>
    $("#genAddress").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'generateAddress',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Wallet address generation success!")
            },

            failure: function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg.toString())
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I assumed we can make the `POST` request without providing any data, but, wasn't sure about how to do it. Ok, just remove the data provision code from the `Ajax` POST request :)

As previously provided, this is the method execute the `POST` request
from the `Spring` controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/generateAddress")
    public String generateAddress() {

        walletService.generateAddress();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```